How to Retrieve Work item updates history for a specific field ie remaining Work using Azure DevOps API
I am using azure devOps work-item updates API to track the changes made to a wort item fields over the time. Specially, I want to retrieve the history history of updates to the Remaining Work  field (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork ).
as per my investigation for work item history devOps update API as follow :
/_apis/wit/workItems/{workItemId}/updates?api-version=7.1
the response includes the list of all updates made to the work item , and I need to manually filter for changes to the Remaining Work field by iteration through the field property of the each update.
Is there a way to filter the results directly in the API call to retrieve updates only for Remaining work.
